# How to insert a shortcode in a dropdown selection that opens a file to download?

Tags: php, wordpress, formidable

I am using a plugin on wordpress that generates a pdf from a form submission. There will be multiple PDF. I want to be able to create a selection that the customer select what pdf they want to use.

The short code is [formidable-download form="7222" layout="100" dataset=[id] title="Entry Form"] When inserting this shortcode you get a link "Entry Form" you click on it and it starts to download the pdf.

I have tried:

```
 <form>
<select>
<option value="">Select</option>
<option>[formidable-download form="7222" layout="100" dataset=[id] title="Entry Form"]</option>
 <option>[formidable-download form="7223" layout="101" dataset=[id] title="Exit Form"]</option>
</select></form>
```

Appears as it should, but when you select "Entry Form or Exit Form" from the dropdown nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert shortcodes in your code, you need to use the do_shortcode() function.

So it'd look something like this:

> do_shortcode('[formidable-download form="7222" layout="100"
>   dataset=[id] title="Entry Form"]');

But it makes not much sense to put a download link inside of a select tag. Are you sure you need it?

Comment: The shortcode starts a script and fills in a pdf, then the pdf starts to download. Best function I can think of. Tried a modal with a list of the forms they can pick from works.... But some reason if I have 3 shortcodes in it. Modal has to be closed three times. Like three modals open at the same time. So dropdown is the only other option since the display is a list.
With your suggestion, I get a page cannot be display tries to bring me to a url with myservlet.do at the end.